# AWK Sum the value of 2 columns and append to record

Tags: linux, awk

Hi I have a csv file that has 4 columns, i want to add numeric values given in column no 3 and 4 and pring in column 5.

I am able to perform sum but output is not printing in new column pls help

```
AK,BANGLA,1095,16  
AL,SAUDI_ARABIA,9592,10593
```

Output should look like

```
AK,BANGLA,1095,16,**1111**  
AL,SAUDI_ARABIA,9592,10593,**20185**
```

My code is only printing sum:

```
awk -F"," '{math[($3+$4)]}END{for (i in math) {print i,math[i]}}'
```

Comment: Please check the state of your caps lock key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine, just that it is printing the sum at the end of the processing.

As you want to have the output in the same line, you can do this:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {print $0, $3+$4}' file
AK,BANGLA,1095,16,1111
AL,SAUDI_ARABIA,9592,10593,20185
```

Comment: Oh, I see :) Note our approaches were exactly the same, only that your `-F','` is redundant as per the `BEGIN{}` block also defining it.

Comment: good point :)  anyway, deleted my answer, since it was pretty much the same.